# Error in android studio please resolve Dependent features configured but no package ID was set

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, sdk

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows Daemon #8: Unexpected error during the link, attempting to stop the daemon.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

Answer (score 0):

***for java project:***

If the module ( dependency feature ) is an library , not an application

use the following configuration in build.gradle ( for the module )

```
plugins {
    // id 'com.android.application'
    id "com.android.library"
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
     //   applicationId "com.xxx.xx.x"
    }
}
```